# Filtering recursive sql query intersecting possible and choosen items

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query

In Sql Server I have the following scenario:

1. Options and relative groups:

   ```
   Groups(Id, Description)
   Options(Id, GroupId, Description)
   ```
2. Nodes configured with options:

   ```
   Nodes(Id, ParentNodeId, Description)
   Configurations(Id, NodeId, OptionId)
   ```

So a node can have one or more options but one per group

3. Users choices:

   ```
   Choices (Guid, OptionId)
   ```

In output I'd like to have nodes, in a recursive way, configured with choosen option. 
For example:

```
Groups
1, "Eyes Color"
2, "Hair Color"
Options
1, 1, "Blue"
2, 1, "Brown"
3, 2, "Blonde"
4, 2, "Black"
Nodes
1, NULL, "Elizabeth"
2, NULL, "John"
Configurations
1, 1, 1 --(Elizabeth, Blue)
1, 1, 3 --(Elizabeth, Blonde)
2, 1, 4 --(John, Black)
```

Possible Choices:

```
Eyes Color: NULL  -- it means there isn't record in choices table for this option
Hair Color: NULL
Result: Elizabeth, John
Eyes Color: "Blue"
Hair Color: NULL
Result: Elizabeth, John
Eyes Color: "Brown"
Hair Color: NULL
Result: John
Eyes Color: NULL
Hair Color: "Blonde"
Result: Elizabeth
Eyes Color: NULL
Hair Color: "Black"
Result: John
Eyes Color: "Blue"
Hair Color: "Black"
Result: John
Eyes Color: "Blue"
Hair Color: "Blonde"
Result: Elizabeth
Eyes Color: "Brown"
Hair Color: "Blonde"
Result: -
Eyes Color: "Brown"
Hair Color: "Black"
Result: John
```

My first problem is to filter. The second problem is to filter in the recursion to not analyze nodes are children of nodes are not included.

Recursion:

```
with livelliRec
as
(
   select 
   0 as level, nodeid, parentid
   from nodes

   union all

   select 
   livellirec.level+1, nodes.nodeid, nodes.parentid
   from nodes
   join livelliRec on nodes.parentid = livellirec.nodeid
)
```

I found a possible solution listing all possible items when a node is not configured for that Group and then verify all chosen items are in possible items. But how to write a query to perform it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should parent node be selected if child node is not choosen?

Comment: Yes, it can. Every node can be configured. It's false the opposite: i have not to include children of a parent node that is not included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example if node is not configured for group, it will be selected:

```
;WITH Filtered AS (
    SELECT N.Id, N.ParentId
    FROM nodes    N
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM configurations     C
        INNER JOIN Options      C_OP  ON C_OP.OptionId = C.OptionId
        INNER JOIN Options      CH_OP ON CH_OP.GroupId  = C_OP.GroupId
        INNER JOIN Choises      CH    ON CH.OptionId = CH_OP.OptionId 
        WHERE C.NodeId = N.Id AND CH.OptionId <> C.OptionId 
    )
), cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS Level, Id, ParentId
    FROM Filtered 
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.Level + 1 AS Level, Id, ParentId
    FROM Filtered  F
    INNER JOIN cte ON F.ParentId = cte.Id
)
SELECT DISTINCT cte.Id
FROM cte
```

Comment: First of all thanks for help. I'm reading the solution and, as i told, my first problem is how to filter. You chose OR condition. I'd ask what happen for case 
Eyes Color: "Brown"
Hair Color: "Blonde"
Result: -
? Maybe result will be "Elizabeth"?

Comment: I will try now. I edited my first post to explain NULL in choices table. Can you edit your answer considering Choices as table? Thanks again

Comment: I'll think about it, It really will be "Elizabeth"

Comment: Don't worry. It's not easy to solve... And it's the first problem :) I'm not very good with USING and WITH instructions.

Comment: First note CH.Value can't be null. Table is built as Choices (Guid, OptionId) and OptionId can't be null. If it's null the record won't be present.

Comment: Table must be Choices (Guid, OptionId, Value)

Comment: OptionId contains the value. The Group is not stored in the Choices Table.

Comment: You can remove also DECLARE @Choise: it's a table

Comment: CH.GroupId is not present, as i told. how can i join with Groups? Thanks, @Mikhail

Comment: I've imroved my join between `configuration` and `choises`

Comment: Maybe we got the solution! I will check in the next weeks. Thanks!